# Proving sequence statement using mathematical induction, $d_n = \frac{2}{n!}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I'm stuck on this homework problem. I must prove the statement using mathematical induction

Given: A sequence $d_1, d_2, d_3, ...$ is defined by letting $d_1 = 2$ and for all integers k $\ge$ 2. 
$$
d_k = \frac{d_{k-1}}{k} 
$$

Show that for all integers $n \ge 1$ , $$d_n = \frac{2}{n!}$$

---

Here's my work:

Proof (by mathematical induction). For the given statement, let the property $p(n)$ be the equation:

$$
d_n = \frac{2}{n!}  
$$

Show that $P(1)$ is true:
The left hand side of $P(1)$ is $d_n$ , which equals $2$ by definition of the sequence.
The right hand side is:

$$ \frac{2}{(1)!} =2 $$

Show for all integers $k \geq 1$, if $P(k)$ is true, then $p(k+1)$ is true.
**Let k** be any integer with $k \geq 1$, and suppose $P(k)$ is true. That is, suppose:  (This is the inductive hypothesis)

$$ d_{k} = \frac{2}{k!} $$

We must show that $P(K+1)$ is true. That is, we must show that:

$$ d_{k+1} = \frac{2}{(k+1)!} $$

**(I thought I was good until here.)**

But the left hand side of $P(k+1)$ is:

$$ d_{k+1} = \frac{d_k}{k+1} $$

By inductive hypothesis:

$$ d_{k+1} = \frac{(\frac{2}{2!})}{k+1} $$

$$ d_{k+1} = \frac{2}{2!}\frac{1}{k+1} $$

**but that doesn't seem to equal** what I needed to prove: $ d_n = \frac{2}{n!}$

Comment: Your initial statement is $P(2)$ not $P(1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not true $$d_{k+1} = \frac{(\frac{2}{2!})}{k+1}$$ since $d_k=\frac{2}{k!}$ not $\frac{2}{2!}$, you actually have $$d_{k+1} = \frac{(\frac{2}{k!})}{k+1}=\frac{(\frac{2}{k!(k+1)})}{1}=\frac{2}{(k+1)!}$$